# How to parallelize the loop in C

Tags: parallel-processing

I solve this problem already. Can you release my ban issue

Comment: What are the "certain code transformations" that you would like to apply?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight just change certain part of code thus can allow it be parallelized

Answer (score 2):

In order to find a strategy for this, it is useful to observe:

- The content of the array prior to the operation is unknown.
- The data type of the array elements is unknown but known to support addition with an integer. This entails, that it cannot be assumed that concurrent operations on elements of the array are sound.
- The last block of 1000 elements (a[100000..100999]) can be processed only *after* the previous block of 1000 has been processed. And so on until the first block (a[1000..1999]).

This entails, that there is no "big parallelizing scheme" possible. But you can well partition those 1000 element blocks and run the processing on them in parallel.

```
typedef struct Range_tag { From : int; To : int } Range_t;
int a[101000];
for( b = 1000; b < 101000; b+=1000)
{
     Range_t jobs[10] = { {b,b+100}, {b+100,b+200}, ... {b+900; b+1000} };
     run_parallel(jobs,10,[&a](Range_t job) { 
         for( i = job.From; i < job.To; i++ ) a[i] = a[i-1000]+1;
     });
}
```

Alternative solution:

Operations on the 1000 subsets: s_i: [a[i],a[i+1000],...] for i in 0..999 are orthogonal. So you could as well schedule 1000 jobs for each of these strands.

In f# it would look like this:

```
let a = Array.init 101000 (fun i -> i)
let meddle() =
    [|0..999|]
    |> Array.Parallel.iter
        (fun s ->
            for i in 1..100 do
                let pivot = s + 1000 * i
                a.[pivot] <- a.[pivot-1000] + 1
        )
meddle()
```

Answer (score 1):

What leads you to the conclusion that threads do help here? Have you benchmarked your code? Is this code the hotspot of your calculation? Premature optimization is the root of all evil!

I am not sure threading will help you on `100000` iterations here for that calculation. You can try [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/wp/). But do a benchmark to verify its working for your case. You definitely have to avoid false-sharing to get the most out of your hardware.

Go a step back and take a look at the whole picture. Is there something wrong with your algorithm? What is the real hotspot in your code? Benchmark it and then fix the problem.

Comment: As mentioned in my post - that depends on what you need. Why do you even need threads? This loop can't be that time critical that it needs to be handled through threads. And if it is then try OpenMP. Is it an exercise from school or whats the task here?

Comment: Questioning the question is not productive. It could be a study and not a practical problem, after all. And you **can** parallelize this within chunks of 1000 elements.

Comment: I don't think so. I can't give an answer to his comment because the answer depends on more information. A study about threading or just understanding the concept of threads in for-loops are a total different thing than fixing a specific for-loop. Sure you **can** optimize it, but the loop will be optimized away anyway. So what do you want to thread here? And therefore I added some questions to get a clearer picture and give him a better answer. So what is wrong with that?

Comment: @HelloWorld Welcome to real life! :) Whenever you are given an incomplete specification, which is ALWAYS, you have to get started somehow. The typical procedure is that you write a document yourself which specifies WHAT you will build, based on the facts you were given. Then, the dialog starts...

Comment: That's not the point. If it's a study or just an excercise I can assume he knows how to deal with the information he gets. If it's a code-snippet from production I would like to get the context to be able to help him. Just telling him how to thread the loop when having some doubts that its used in the right concext wouldn't help.

Answer (score -1):

You don't want parallel threads access the same memory, so what you can do is create one loop which accesses the even memory locations, and another loop which accesses the odd memory locations:

```
/* even */
for(i = 0;i<100000;i+=2)
{
 a[i+1000] = a[i] +1;
}

/* odd */
for(i = 1;i<100000;i+=2)
{
 a[i+1000] = a[i] +1;
}
```

Comment: False sharing galore?

Comment: Why should that help? When the compiler doesn't turn your code into some reasonable code, you might even loose performance because the CPU has to grab the cache lines again from the beginning when the second loop begins and starts from the beginning.

Comment: Could you prove your statement with a reference or some documentation?